# How to batch process a directory of mp4 files to remove their metadata?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, batch-processing

I convert one mp4 file using ffmpeg to remove all metadata from the mp4 file  with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4
```

This works fine but I want a bash script that will automatically remove all metadata of a directory containing mp4 files, with minimum interaction.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "fixed_$f"; done
```

Bash replaces `*.mp4` with names of all matching files in current directory. Each step the loop passes, `f` contains one of the file names.

Or use a subdirectory:

```
mkdir converted
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "converted/$f"; done
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus thanks it works! :-) Is there anyway to add a remove the original files in the directory after removal of metadata, and then keep the updated files as per original names of the file?

Comment: @Cyrus Please, add an explanation, we are not here just to "do the work"...the next guy that comes to this needs to learn and understand...otherwise a simple variation of the request would make this solution useless..

Comment: @MerakMarey: Thank you for the useful hint. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This lists all the files (and only the files) in the current directory:

```
for /r %i in (*) do echo %i
```

Also if you run that command in a batch file you need to double the % signs.

```
for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

It will go something like this. Create a file, call it test.cmd and copy this inside the file.

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    ffmpeg -i %%f -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy %%~nf-out.mp4
)
```

The `-n` works as a substitution for only the name part.

Comment: Apologies, I wanted a bash script that will batch convert all my mp4 files using the command I gave above, in a batch process.

Comment: So, you want a working solution instead of pointing directions..correct?

Comment: Yes I'm not versed with shell or batch scripting. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer. Remember to vote if it works. ;)

Comment: Apologies I am looking for a bash shell script not windows bat script?